# Programmatically add a WSO2 API manager store user (subscriber)

Tags: wso2

Is it possible to programmatically add a store user?

I found the following API manager service urls;

```
https://localhost:8243/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl
https://localhost:8243/services/APIAuthenticationService?wsdl
https://localhost:8243/services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService?wsdl
https://localhost:8243/services/RestApiAdmin?wsdl
```

but I get a white screen. The following directories are also empty:

```
/opt/wso2am-1.3.1/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/apis/xml
/opt/wso2am-1.3.1/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/apis/rest
/opt/wso2am-1.3.1/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/apis/json
```

Seems like it is not implemented yet.

I'll appreciate any update on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the below comment which is an answer given for a similar question like yours.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1311?focusedCommentId=66003&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_66003

regards

Comment: Great! Thanks. Using the UserAdmin service, I guess I can access the service and send a payload containing new users I want to add.